# how to send splunk email using outlook credentials

Tags: splunk

I have splunk installed and currently I'm using SMTP server local host with port no-25. I have tried using gmail and its default port number. but I want to send email using Outlook credentials instead of gmail or smtp local host.

Comment: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Enterprise-Security/How-to-integrate-email-alerts-into-splunk/m-p/469231 check this

Answer (score 1):

Good news is that you can configure the outgoing e-mail server from the UI. You can browse to **Settings > Server settings > Email settings.**

[image]

On the page below you'll find the IMAP/POP/SMTP settings for common e-mail providers including Outlook.com / Microsoft 365. This together with your username/password should get you sending e-mails from Splunk in no time.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353

Comment: Hi Honky, Thank you for the response. Since we have outlook, I have tried as follows smtp.office365.com:587 But its throwed error stating " Sending the test email failed: command="sendemail", Connection closed unexpectedly" Please suggest your view on the same. Do we need to change any configuration setup

Comment: Hi Gayathri, try to toggle Enable TLS in the Splunk config. Another thing to try is to see if you can reach the smtp host/port from your Splunk instance by establishing a console connection and running "nc -vz smtp.office365.com 587" or "telnet smtp.office365.com 587"

Comment: Hi Honkey, Yes I tried it. but the results are same. I got error "command=sendemail",Connection unexpectedly closed while sending mail to =XXX.com"

I tried to toggle Enable TLS in splunk config and host name and port I mentioned as "smtp.office365.com:587" but it returned same results